# Add On-Condition of Full Outer Join to Selection

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume I have tables `employees (employee_id, employee_name, department_id)` and `departments (department_id, department_name)`. I want the full outer join on both tables **with** the `department_id` which happens to be the on condition. It shall always be filled (either with the value from the employee table or with the value of the department table - whichever value is not null).

```
SELECT
   employee_name,
   department_name
FROM
   employees e
FULL OUTER JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id;
```

How would I integrate the `department_id` into the query above? The syntax is in postgresql. (I do know I could join it - but actually the information concerning the `department_id` should be available during query processing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT
   employee_name,
   department_name,
   COALESCE (e.department_id, d.department_id)
FROM
   employees e
FULL OUTER JOIN departments d ON d.department_id = e.department_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would typically use a `USING` clause in a full outer join:

```
SELECT
   department_id,
   e.employee_name,
   d.department_name
FROM employees e
FULL OUTER JOIN departments d USING (department_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `using` clause:

```
SELECT department_id, e.employee_name, e.department_name
FROM employees e FULL OUTER JOIN
     departments d
     USING (department_id);
```

Note that this requires that the foreign key have the same name as the primary key and you do not qualify the column in the `SELECT`.